# Hanning window size in EEG power spectrum

Tags: neuroscience, eeg, signal-processing

I must compute the power spectrum density of sleep EEGs. I was told by an experienced scientist that the process goes as follows:

- Artifact detect/reject the EEG
- Compute the power spectrum for every 2 or 5 second subset of the EEG.
- Take the average power spectrum density of those 2 or 5 second subsets within each 30 second epoch.

Thus, the final data results in an average spectral density for each 30 second epoch, where this average comes from averaging the spectral densities of the 2 or 5 second chunks within it.

The only issue I have found with this general procedure is that I can't find any info on what the Hanning window size should be. I'm using Welch's method to compute the spectrum of each 5 second chunk within each 30 second epoch. I have used a Hanning window size of $2 f_s$ or equivalently 2 seconds but I chose this value arbitrarily.

*Note*. My EEGs have a 500Hz sampling frequency, so there are 500 samples per second.

What should the size of the Hanning window be?